# ANSIBLE: Is there a way to assign a value to nested dynamic variables in vars file?

Tags: ansible

I'm tyring to use the find module to find file patterns with variables from an external vars file that has dynamic variables in a list of dictionaries. How can I assign values to those dynamic variables in vars file while accessing them from the playbook?

deletememes.yml:

```
---
  name: generic name
  hosts: all
  vars_files: vars.yml
  tasks:
   - set_fact: 
      combinedlist: "{{ first_list + second_list }}"

   - find: 
      paths: "{{ item.0.path }}" # pass a value(item.1.username?) here for the username in the vars file  
          patterns: "{{ item.0.extension }}" 
        register: someRegister
        with_items:
         - combinedlist
         - usernameList # for the value in
```

vars.yml

```
---
    first_list:
     - { path : "/Users/{{ username }}/memes/" , extension : '{{ username }}_*.jpg'}
     - { path : "/someOtherFolder/{{ username }}/catVideos/" , extension : '{{ item.username }}_*.mp4'}  

    second_list:
     - { path : "/{{ memesrc }}/memes/" , extension : '{{ memesrc }}_*.gif'}
```

ERROR:

```
"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'username' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to have been in 'deletememes.yml'
```

Comment: You can't do iterations/loops in the var file, you need to process the variables in the playbook. Can you have just the `external_list_of_users` and `external_list_memesites` in the var file?

Comment: @MMT Thank you for the response. I have edited the code as it was a little bit confusing. 
My idea was to have it modular, so in the future I could add more patterns in the vars file. I am wondering if it is possible to assign a value to the username - dynamic variable inside the list of dictionaries inside vars files(nested variables?) from the pb, while using the key:value.

Answer (score 1):

Vars files are not dynamic.  You would have to make those assignments in `set_fact` tasks.  Now, you have to break up the variable from the text and use the string concatination operator, `+`.  I'm only showing one list here:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local

  vars:
    external_list_of_users:
      - username: fred
      - username: barney
      - username: wilma
      - username: betty

  tasks:
  - name: Create arrays
    set_fact:
      first_list: []

  - name: Put items in arrays
    set_fact:
      first_list: "{{ first_list + [ { 'path' : '/Users/'+item.username+'/memes/' , 'extension' : item.username+'_*.jpg' } ] }}"
    with_items:  "{{ external_list_of_users }}"

  - name: Show vars
    debug:
      var: first_list
```

The result of that last task is:

```
TASK [Show vars] *******************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "first_list": [
        {
            "extension": "fred_*.jpg", 
            "path": "/Users/fred/memes/"
        }, 
        {
            "extension": "barney_*.jpg", 
            "path": "/Users/barney/memes/"
        }, 
        {
            "extension": "wilma_*.jpg", 
            "path": "/Users/wilma/memes/"
        }, 
        {
            "extension": "betty_*.jpg", 
            "path": "/Users/betty/memes/"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I have edited the list of vars file, as it was confusing.
My idea was to have it modular, so in the future I could add patterns in the vars file.
How can I change the dynamic variable in vars file from the playbook.

Comment: Well, as MMT said, you can't loop over items is a vars file.  As for the `someOtherFolder` stuff, just add ` + [ { 'path' : '/someOtherFolder/'+item.username+'/catVideos/' , 'extension' : item.username+'_*.mp4' } ]` inside the double-squirelly-brackets, and it should be fine.

Comment: You could put variables such as `path_prefix`, `path_postfix`, and `extension` in your vars files.

Comment: I would like to keep the structure as is and not add the dictionaries to the playbook, as it would break the modularity of it. Is it possible to use a filter like item.username.combinedlist | deafult("fred") or some kind of template filter to assign the value to the dynamic variable from vars files in the playbook?

Comment: You don't have to have the fixed dictionaries in the playbook.  I just did that for convenience.  What you also do is have that stuff in a jinja2 template.  One play could run that template on localhost and put the results into the /tmp directory.  Then have another play with the `vars_files` option that loads that temp file.

Comment: OK -- now you've changed the question around quite a bit.

Comment: Yes, I realiesed it was quite confusing